# SignalR with non asp.net Client. Connect from JS to a Hub on a remote server

Tags: .net, signalr

I've used SignalR a lot in the context of a .net MVC application, invoked from client JS and native code.

I want to be able to generate the hub proxy from a simple web/js page, and connect to a hub which is on a WebApi service on a remote server.

Is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Yes, SignalR has no MVC requirement and it also has nothing to do with webapi. Maybe you're looking for self hosting instructions http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: Hi david.  yeah, maybe I've confused it by mentioning WebApi. Essentially all i need is the ability to use a single web page with some JS in it as the client, and connect to a remote hub. (not needing a global asax with routetable.maphubs....)

Comment: The self hosting instructions look to be what i need.  thanks

Comment: @davidfowl Dead link. Could it be this link that you were referring to: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host